# Is there a way to work with times of the day without including the date aspect?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I want to create a an array of times of day, this is to store the times when a student starts and ends school. Since this is a typical weekly setup, this doesn't require the date aspect to be included so I was wondering if I could store these times in an array without having to include the date aspect, since its irrelevant?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let date = NSDate()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:MM:SS"
let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(date)

"12:06:70"
```

So you could format a date as a `String` comprising only the date component and create a `[String]`. However I believe but may be wrong that there will likely often be a good case for storing the time-date as the original type. For example if you need to later perform time related calculations.